# How to inject a method into a class at runtime without ASM?

Tags: java, reflection, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

In past versions of the bytecode manipulation framework Mixin, there was a method called `prepareConfigs(MixinEnvironment)`.  A nonstandard, but *very* commonly-used, way to bootstrap Mixins at a certain phase of the lifecycle was to access and call that method using Reflection.

In later versions of the framework, that method's signature has been changed to `prepareConfigs(MixinEnvironment, Extensions)`, causing the Reflection-based usages to break.

The owner of the library has made it clear that breaking this was intentional and will not allow a fix.  However, even though it was bad practice to use that strategy, the usage was common enough that end-users are unable to use many apps that relied on the framework.

I would like to make a compatibility patch that adds the old method back to the class to stop the crashes.  Problem is, this requires injecting a method into a class that is *restricted from being transformed by ASM*.

The *only* requirement is that the method does not throw a `NoSuchMethodException` when accessed via reflection, since I'm easily able to implement their intended behavior somewhere else.  It doesn't actually need to do anything, it just needs to stop the exception from being thrown.

I've heard people offhand-mention a way to declare class members that can only be accessed by Reflection, but I couldn't find any details on it.

Is there a way to do what I need without ASM?

Comment: How is that class "restricted from being transformed by ASM"? ASM just parses and writes java bytecode.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Certain classes, like transformers and other classes that create transformers, are not allowed to be transformer targets themselves in this ecosystem.

Comment: you might override a class with a classloader when you have the source of the orignial you can override that one in your project, or mix the new and old code by just adding  the method

Comment: If, as your comment implies, the ecosystem forbids *any* transformation there is no sense in asking for doing it “without ASM”, as whether you use ASM or not is not relevant to the restriction. Besides that, it’s not clear why it should matter whether Reflection is used or not. Changing a method in this way breaks *all* callers.

Comment: @Holger It only forbids it from being targeted by an ASM class transformer; it doesn't stop it from potentially being changed through other less-intuitive ways such as declaring a method on a Groovy metaclass or another way that I am not currently aware of.  I've heard someone mention in a thread off-hand that there was a way to do what I need but with the side effect of the injected method only being accessible by reflection.  Since the only callers of this method are using reflection anyway, that wouldn't pose a problem.

Comment: How does it even know whether it has been transformed using ASM or “through other less-intuitive ways”?

Comment: Custom ClassLoader implementation that places modules onto the classpath at runtime. Useful for an ecosystem built off of transforming another source, like for game modding.  Only classes that aren't restricted from being ASM-transformed get passed to the group of ASM class transformers; normally, you'd restrict your class transformer from being transformed to prevent weird stuff from happening like the transformer trying to transform itself or something, but this library disallowed all of its files from being targeted by ASM transformers.  It doesn't stop any non-ASM methods, though.

Comment: “that places modules onto the classpath at runtime” contains two contradictions at once. Modules are never placed on the classpath. Further, loading classes through a custom class loader does not place them on the classpath. But the main problem with your explanation is this mythical entity “the group of ASM class transformers”. A class using the ASM library does not become member of some “group of ASM class transformers”. Did you know that even the JDK itself uses the ASM library under the hood?

Comment: @Holger Dude, I'm using Minecraft Forge. In your coremod, you tell it where your `IClassTransformer` implementations are and it calls their `transform` methods with each class as they're loaded. While being loaded, if a class has been marked as an ASM-exclusion, the method won't be called on it. All mod and coremod jars are also searched for and added to the classloader at runtime. I may be getting your specific terms wrong, but I know what I'm talking about. Now can you please stop looking for a "gotcha" and actually help? I know the JVM supports this, I just don't know the way to do it.

Comment: Don’t blame others for your inability to ask a meaningful question. If you want to know how to do class transformation without using Minecraft’s framework, ask how to do class transformation without using Minecraft’s framework. How is anyone supposed to know that you have a Minecraft specific problem when you keep talking about the entirely unrelated ASM library? Now that you managed to tell about your actual problem, after only five days, [edit] your question so that readers don’t have to search the comments to find the only useful information.

Comment: @Holger Because it's not a Minecraft-specific question. The only things that matter are that I a) want to inject a method into a class and b) can't use ASM, two things that I already detailed in the question. You're the one who's spent the last five days pushing for information that didn't matter.

Comment: You problem is that an `IClassTransformer` will not be called for the code of another `IClassTransformer`. That’s regardless of whether the `IClassTransformer` uses ASM or not. If, on the other hand, you implement the class transformation without that framework, e.g. using the `ClassFileTransformer` of the Instrumentation API, you don’t have the problem but still can use the ASM library. As said, the JDK itself uses the ASM library as well and is not stopped, as it does not depend on `IClassTransformer`. Stop confusing Minecraft’s `IClassTransformer` with ASM and you’re halfway to a solution.

Comment: Ok, thank you for giving me a solution that uses ASM. Using a non-API ASM transformer implementation is not an option. Do you have any solutions that don't require ASM?

Comment: What is “non-API ASM transformer implementation” supposed to mean? You can use ASM, BCEL, Javassist, some other library, or create the necessary byte array by hand, it all doesn’t matter. The only thing that matters, is how you turn the processed byte array into a modification of the class. There are only two options, either you use the API that does not allow you to do what you want to do, or you use a different API, like the Instrumentation API.

Comment: @Holger Those other methods sound like great ideas! That's the kind of thing I was asking for!  I don't want to implement my own different version of one of ASM's class transformers since there's already an API for that in that environment, but something else that DOESN'T directly use ASM would have less of a chance of conflicting with the API.  However, I'd prefer some way of directly injecting the method declaration into the Class object's declared methods if that's at all possible. I'll edit the question to be clearer about that.